# How do I reverse the order of data from Firebase in my RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm facing the problem that I want my uploaded data to be on the top of my RecyclerView.
I´m already displaying the data from Firebase in a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.
I have read a couple posts about this problem but wasn´t able to find the right solution.

I can´t figure out for example where in my Code I have to implement the following method I found in another post:

```
    @Override public Item getItem(int pos) {return super.getItem(getCount() -1- pos);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to reverse order of items in gridlayoutmanager, basically you can set it in its constructor

`new GridLayoutManager(getContext, spanCount, LinearLayoutManger.HORIZONTAL, true)`

Comment: For clarification: I want the item I uploaded last to be the first item in the gridlayout. I´m also using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

I think that idea is to make your own Adapter that will have implements of Adapter. Then you override method.